# Extract integers from std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing simple OBJ loader and I encountered next problem - I have to extract integers from next `std::string`:

```
f v0/vt0/vn0 v1/vt1/vn0 ... vk/vtk/vnk
```

where `vk`, `vtk`, `vnk` are int values and there is no space between `/` and the values and only one space between groups.

As the files can be quite large and this type of lines may appear more than 100000 times I need an efficient way to extract the integers from strings like this one.

EDIT:

As Jesse asked this is my current approach(I assume data is in the right format!):

```
int p, t, n;
const char* l = line.c_str() + 2;

for (int vIndex = 0; l && sscanf(l, "%d/%d/%d", &p, &t, &n) == 3; ++vIndex)
{
    //do something with vertex
    l = strchr(l, ' ');
    if (l)
    {
        l += 1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't think it gets more efficient than looping though the string and doing the math.

Comment: @Jesse, that is not very helpful to immediately assume this person is lazy. look at his reputation 3K he has helped many already, hardly the traits of a lazy person. Maybe he did not have time or does not want a fix to something but instead get a brand new approach. If you do not want to help him then skip this question instead of being negative please.

Comment: I wouldn't use sscanf, very inefficient (as a general rule).

Comment: @Rob: Well, he provided his approach. I didn't think that was too much to ask for.

Comment: @john I know my current approach is not efficient, this is why I asked here:)

Comment: @Felics Well as I said, loop through the string and do the math yourself.

Comment: @Jesse, sure but the added lazy was unwarranted.

Comment: @Felics A simple Finite State Machine (FSM) is about as efficient as you are going to get. I would just hand code it because the format doesn't seem very complicated, but there are tools that will generate FSM code for you if you prefer (Ragel for instance).

Comment: Ok have you tried a finite state machine? THey are extremely efficient at this sort of task.

Comment: LOL we typed it at the same time John :).

Comment: @Rob great minds etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::strtol`, this is quite neat in that it will return the end of the current parse, and you can continue from there. So let's say that you guarantee that you read three digits each time, something like the following sketch could work..

```
char *p = line.c_str() + 1;

while (p)
{
  long v0 = std::strtol(++p, &p, 0); // at the end, p points to '/'
  long v1 = std::strtol(++p, &p, 0); // at the end, p points to '/'
  long v2 = std::strtol(++p, &p, 0); // at the end, p points to ' '
  // On the last one, p will be null...
}
```

Comment: And where is the error checking code ? (how do you know whether `std::strtol` failed to read an integer)

Comment: @MatthieuM. you can't give everything away! ;)

Comment: Valid comment since `strtol` has a horrible interface. `std::stoi` is much better. But do check for `*p=='\0'` as that's the normal termination condition here.

Answer (score 2):

[std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) is quite fast:

```
const char* l = line.c_str() + 2;
while (l)
{
    char* c;
    long num = std::strtol(l, &c, 10);
    if (l == c)
    {
        break;
    }
    //do something with vertex
    l = c + 1; // move past the slash
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `l = c+1` to move past the slash? This increments l one char at a time, and converting `"vt123"` would produce 123, 23 and 3.

Comment: @Nim, MSalters: Thanks for the feedback. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Use boost spirit, it is far more powerful and allow easy evolution.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html

Here is a example solving your problem by putting your vertices in a vector. If you want to call another function, see phoenix doc:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit.html#phoenix.starter_kit.lazy_functions

I admit Phoenix/Spirit has a high entry cost, but I think it is worth the pain.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/object/construct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/container.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::tuple<double, double, double> vertex;
typedef std::vector<vertex> Vertices;

template <typename Iterator>
bool vector_creator(Iterator first, Iterator last, Vertices& vector)
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,            
        (
            'f' >> *(qi::double_ >> '/' >> qi::double_>> '/' >> qi::double_)
            [ 
                phoenix::push_back(phoenix::ref(vector),
                    phoenix::construct<vertex>(qi::_1, qi::_2 , qi::_3))
            ]
        ), qi::space);

    return r;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    while (getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
        {
            break;
        }

        Vertices Vertices;
        if (vector_creator(str.begin(), str.end(), Vertices))
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded: " << Vertices.size() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing failed." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program run:

```
> a.exe
f 1/1.2/-3 0.5/2.3/0 2./5/6 .3/.2/9888
Parsing succeeded: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &B1, &B2, &C1, &C2, &D1, &D2 ) == 9 )
{
    A3 = B3 = C3 = 0;
    ...
}
else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &A3, &B1, &B2, &B3, &C1, &C2, &C3 ) == 10 )
{
    ...
}
else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", Prefix, &A1, &A3, &B1, &B3, &C1, &C3 ) == 7 )
{
    A2 = B2 = C2 = 0;
    ...
}
else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &B1, &B2, &C1, &C2 ) == 7 )
{
    A3 = B3 = C3 = 0;
    ...
}
```